# Circle Bound to Marker - Need: Re-sizable, but not draggable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hopefully an easy one...

I have a collection of myMarkers[] on my map.  I can successfully bind a Circle to the current/clicked marker. With "editable: true", the circle is re-sizable as desired, but when the circle is dragged, it also drags my maker out of position (well, duh, its bound to the marker) - not the desired function.

Questions:

1. Setting "editable: true" and "draggable: false" - still draggable.  Is such a combination possible?
2. I can live with a draggable Circle, if I can un-bind it from the current marker, that would be ideal.  Is this possible?  Maybe create a dummy marker at same position as the current marker and bind to THAT instead? (invisible icon, or behind current marker(s)).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Found a solution - Circle bound to dummy marker, set invisible.  I cannot post my solution/code for another 8 hours.  Odd....  >>> Posted above <<<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be easy enough using a dummy marker!

```
  function addCircle() {

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapMarkers[currentMarker])
      postion: new google.maps.LatLng(mapMarkers[currentMarker])
      myPosition = mapMarkers[currentMarker].getPosition();
      map.panTo(myPosition);
      map.setZoom(9);

      circle = new google.maps.Circle({
           map: map,
           editable: true,
           fillColor: '#ffffff',
           fillOpacity: 0.3,
           strokeColor: '#ff0000',
           strokeOpacity: 1.0,
           strokeWeight: 1.5,
           radius: 80467.2         // 50 MILES in meters
      });

      var dummyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myPosition,
          visible: false,
          map: map,
      });

      circle.bindTo('center', dummyMarker, 'position');

   }
```